# Drupal 7 Views bulk operations based on terms

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to do bulk operations based on terms instead of node id. For example, I have a term called "XXXX", I have selected this term for 10 contents. So, in manage views I want to display only the term name, if when user selecting that term and do publish/unpublish, that 10 contents should be publish/unpublish.

Is it possible with Rules? Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Please use http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ for Drupal related answers. Other than that, VBO won't work like this (as you said it's based on nids) and Rules doesn't provide a "Load node by term id" action. You would need to write a custom module for that. But you can use the taxonomy term view and add VBO actions to it.